# How do I use auto generated id in code with Spring Data?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When entity is created it usually receives some auto generated int value for primary key. And I have entity called 'Attribute', that can have a list of related 'Parameter' entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTES")
public class Attribute {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Parameter> parameters;
```

And next I have entity called 'Parameter' that needs to be linked with 'Attribute'. So when I create a 'Parameter' I need to specify its 'Attribute'.
How do I do that? What's the trick?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARAMS")
public class Parameter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "PARAMETER_ID", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    private Attribute attribute;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;
```

Comment: In `Parameter` entity use `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`. In this case `attribute` cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I think you are asking about creating an instance of Parameter without having an instance of Attribute at hand? You must have an ATTRIBUTE_ID since it may not be null and there are various ways that you could proceed. Assuming you already have an Attribute instance you could explicitly add it's primary key as an attribute of Parameter e.g.

```
@Column(nullable=false, name="ATTRIBUTE_ID")
private Integer attributeId;
```

and of course create getters/setters and set the id explicitly. There are other strategies if you have an instance of the Attribute you could just add you Parameter in the Attribute and use a cascading persist.

Comment: Not exactly. For example I need to add a 'Parameter' to already existing 'Attribute'. I can get that 'Attribute' with help of JPA repository through findById method, but how do I know the id to look for?

Comment: I'm sorry I have some trouble understanding your question. If you have an existing Attribute you also have an ID (the one you used in findById?) and you also have a getter on the Attribute or you should create one in a similar fashion as I mentioned in my previous answer. I think I'm not really answering your question because it is still not clear to me.

Comment: Ok, I'm really lost here, so I may sound random. But let's imagine a situation. Table 'ATTRIBUTES' doesn't exist for now. I start my application, table creates automatically, some Attribute (let's say it has name 'Details') is created by some initializing script as well. I will need to add this Attribute to my objects and later specify Parameters, but how will I know, what id this Attribute'll have?

Comment: The id of your attribute is decided by the sequence and is a technical information. If created by a database script you don't know the id. You would have to search for an Attribute by another parameter e.g. name = 'Details'. If you create the entity in Java under a Transaction then you will generate the id when you persist it and can see it with the corresponding getter. To query you would probably use the EntityManager or a Spring Data Repository.